# How to create 3 node (1 master,2 worker) elasticsearch cluster on docker swarm?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-swarm

I want to create 3 node elasticsearch cluster with 1 master node and 2 worker node. ES v6 and Swarm v1.18. Anyone could help?

Comment: Google is your friend: https://sematext.com/blog/docker-elasticsearch-swarm/ :-)

Comment: Swarm v1.18?  Do you mean 18.03 the latest docker engine?

Comment: yes, the latest docker engine.

Answer (score 0):

You need create a stack of elasticsearch with 3 services.

1. Create file 'elasticsearch-swarm.yaml'

```
sudo nano elasticsearch-swarm.yaml
```

2. Type the instruction

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  elasticsearch1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.2.4
    hostname: elasticsearch1
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch1-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - cluster.name=elasticsearch-cluster
      - "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts=tasks.elasticsearch1"
      - "network.host=0.0.0.0"
      - "node.max_local_storage_nodes=2"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
      - elasticsearch_distributed
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      restart_policy:
        delay: 30s
        max_attempts: 10
        window: 120s
volumes:
  elasticsearch1-data:

networks:
  elasticsearch_distributed:
    driver: overlay
```

3. Deploy stack file

```
sudo docker stack deploy --compose-file=elasticsearch-swarm.yaml elasticsearch
```

This command will create 3 replicas of elasticsearch server inside a same cluster.

If you receive a error that you don't have **max_map_count** enough and ask to set at least **262144** execute the bellow steps:

1. Edit file /etc/sysctl.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

2. Add the key in the end of file

```
vm.max_map_count=262144
```

3. Apply settings to the current instance

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54838371/308851 is highly relevant.